# Call same step with different type of argument in BDD

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I'm writing testcases using BDD. I have a scenario where I'm stuck

I'm generating random data using below step

```
When generate random data for registration form
```

There is Bean class which have some fields like `fname, lname, email, pass` while i call above step  it generates random data and filled in that bean class

Now  it returns that bean class object and I'm storing that in `formdata` variable

```
And store into 'formdata'
```

Now i want to send that to my username field like below

```
And enter firstname as '${formdata}'
```

code step for same :

```
@QAFTestStep(stepName = "enterFirstName", description = "enter firstname as {0}")
public void enterFirstName(Map<String, Object> data) {
    sendKeys(data.get("firstname").toString(), element);
}
```

Its working fine but suppose in some case i have to send only string  as below

```
And enter firstname as 'Narendra'
```

Step would be :

```
@QAFTestStep(stepName = "enterFirstName", description = "enter firstname as {0}")
public void enterFirstName(String fname) {

    sendKeys(fname, element);

}
```

Then how do i manage these 2 code as single method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below solution which helped me to do the same as i expecting:

```
@QAFTestStep(stepName = "enterFirstName", description = "enter firstname as {0}")
public void enterFirstName(Object obj) {

    if (obj instanceof LinkedTreeMap) {
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
        sendKeys(map.get("firstname").toString(), "regpage.firstname.textbox");

    } else if (obj instanceof String) {
        sendKeys(obj.toString(), "regpage.firstname.textbox");
    } else if (obj instanceof RandomRegisterDataGenerator) {
        RandomRegisterDataGenerator data = (RandomRegisterDataGenerator) obj;
        sendKeys(data.getFirstname(), "regpage.firstname.textbox");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need for generating random strings for a broader input coverage. I would suggest forming a logic based on delimiters.

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    enterFirstName("iamkenos");
    enterFirstName("${formdata}");
}

public static void enterFirstName(String fname) {
    System.out.println(transformData(fname));
}

public static String transformData(String data) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\$\\{.+}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        //do some logic on your data;
        data = "my new data 123";
    }

    return data;
}
```

This will however require you to:

call the `transformData(arg)` every time

stick to a fixed delimeter e.g. `${}`

**Output:**

```
iamkenos
my new data 123
```

Comment: Thanks, But here i  need to design a method which can accept different types of parameter in single one

Comment: Try looking into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [form-data-bean](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/databeans.html#form-data-bean)? It is preferred, where you can populate bean with one filed or all field and it will fill UI accordingly.

You can have step to populate bean and fill UI inside your bean class like below:

```
//Object obj: argument can be string or map or json string or xml key
@QAFTestStep( description = "fill registration form using {data}")
public void fillRegistrationFormWithData(Object obj) {

   this.fillData(obj);
   this.fillUiElements();
}

@QAFTestStep( description = "fill registration form with random data")
public void fillRegistrationFormWithRandomData() {
   this.fillRandomData();
   this.fillUiElements();
}
```